# Add animation to drawLine and drawBitmap

Tags: android, animation, canvas, android-animation

I have a custom view that extends relative layout. In the dispatchDraw method I draw lines and images inside a for loop because i have different start and end points for multiple lines.
I would like to know the easiest way to draw lines with animations from point a to point b in a slow way for example, this animation must be set only for a line that I decide and not for all the others.
I would also like to draw images with animations, I don't want to move the image but I would like to draw the image a little bigger first and then reduce it to the right size, or draw the image from top to bottom. Again this animation must be set only for a image that I decide and not for all the others.

```
@Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int width = getWidth(); 
        int height = getHeight();
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        size = width / (lines);
        insideMargin = size / margin;
        vMargin = (height - lines * size) / 2f; 
        canvas.translate(0,vMargin); 

        for(int x=0; x<lines;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<lines;y++){
                if(/*a condintion is true*/) {
                    //draw line with animation, how to do it?
                }else{
                    canvas.drawLine(x * size,
                            y * size,
                            (x + 1) * size,
                            y* size,
                            paint
                    );
                }

                if(/*a condition is true*/) {
                    //draw bitmap with animation, how to do it?
                }else
                    canvas.drawBitmap(image, src, dest, null);
            }


        }

    }

    //i have on touch event that will call invalidate
```

Comment: see `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator` class documentation and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation) in general

Comment: bit curious what is your condition. if you are drawing many lines will you have condition for each one of them. use objectanimator as suggested by pskink. in case its a custom object you can have a getter or setter and use that as a property.

Comment: My custom view contains many lines in different coordinates, through onTouchEvent I take the coordinates and I can go back to the specific line touched, so I set a boolean for that line. At this point in the dispatchDraw() if the boolean has been set I should draw the line with the animation. Could you give me an example on how to use ObjectAnimator with drawLine / drawBitmap?

Comment: this should help https://proandroiddev.com/android-bring-life-to-your-custom-view-8604ab3967b3 with valueanimator. you would similarly do with object animator but you would need setx sety and getx and gety to and then do as shown in the documentation pskink shared in the first comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ValueAnimator` for your purpose. As I understood, you want to animate values once a touch event occurs. The value returned by the animator must be used for all objects so the animated value should be general as possible. I recommend to use 0 to 1 as float value. You can use this value for the animation. For the bitmap animation, you can define target rectangle start and end size then you can find appropriate size by facilitating the animated fraction value. For the line case, you can use the slope for the animation. I think you already have the line's start and end point so you can use slope and fraction to calculate animated end point.